# Starting crhome/msedge with C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, processstartinfo

Been running Test Complete in C# with Visual Studio.  The tests create an html file, and at the end of the test, we do a

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", newPath);
```

(newPath has the url it is like C:\Automation\Logs\Html\4_18_2022_8_28_38_AM.html).
This works fine, but iexplore is not going to be around much longer.  So I am trying to use Chrome or Edge.  So I try

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", newPath); or
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msedge.exe", newPath);
```

A window appears to come up for a few seconds, and then disappears.  The same thing happens from a command prompt

```
start msedge.exe
start chrome.exe
```

in C# I even tried with the full path to Chrome, but same error.  It seems to work if there is an instance of Chrome up already, but I can't even start an instance with no parameters.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should just use whatever browser the user has choosen to be the default one. Start the url not the browser

Comment: Why not just `Process.Start(newPath);` and let Windows open whatever is the default handler for HTML files?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that is the first thing I did

Comment: with Connect I think